# AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am getting the Error `AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'Session'`. I want to create token based authentication. I am getting token through through some servie, which is not my concern, but problem is that I am getting attribute error.

```
from flask import session, abort
from functools import wraps    
app =Flask(__name__)    
def authenticated_resource(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("authenticated"):
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return abort(403) # unauthenticated
    return decorated  
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error=None
  if request.method=='POST':
    if request.form['username']!='admin' or request.form['password']!='1234':
      error ='Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:          
      username=request.form['username']
      password=request.form['password']
      print 'username=', username
      print 'password=', password          
      auth_url='http://192.168.206.133:5000/v2.0'
      token = getToken(username=username, password=password, tenant_name=tenant_name)

      session["authenticated"] = True
      session["auth_token"] = token_dict

      return redirect(url_for('getstats'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/metering')
@authenticated_resource
def getstats():
    token =session.get("auth_token")
    print 'token=',token
    return render_template('metering.html') 

@app.route('/projects')
def get_projects():
    auth=v2.Password(auth_url="http://192.168.206.133:5000/v2.0/", username="admin", password="1234", tenant_id='020377f522324546b072af92862e6466')
    sess=session.Session(auth=auth,verify=False)
    nova = client.Client(2, session=sess)
    instances =nova.servers.list()  
    def serializer(m):
      ret={}
      ret['Name']=m.name
      ret['Id']= m.id
      return ret
    context ={      
      'instances': [serializer(m) for m in instances],
      'project':[{'Id':'project', 'Name':'project'}] # Here added project option for group_by select option, 
       #previously It was showing only instance option, but now it is also show project option
    }
    return jsonify(context)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.secret_key='super secret key'
   #app.config['SESSION_TYPE']='filesystem'
   app.debug= True
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5001)
```

**Trace of Full Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vagrant/flaskhorizon/flaskhorizon/flaskhorizon.py", line 140, in get_projects
    sess=session.Session(auth=auth,verify=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'Session'
```

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of the error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks for interest, I have updated question with full trace of error......

Comment: Is `flaskhorizon` your project? Can you show us the `get_projects()` code for that? It is *that code* that fails here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I updated code, previously I was doing hard coded, This is openstack project....https://www.openstack.org/

Comment: @MartijnPieter, could you suggest me where I am wrong....

Comment: So what is `sess=session.Session(auth=auth,verify=False)` supposed to do? That throws the exception, because the Flask `session` object has no `Session` attribute.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for reply, I solved the problem `from keystoneclient import session 
from flask import session` It was due to I include two different session, Thanks for pointing out.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported Flask's `session` object.  You also seem to expect that `session` refers to somthing else that contains a `Session` class.  You need to fix your imports so the two are distinct.  You can add an alias to one of the imports, so that the names do not overlap.  Or import the `Session` class directly.

```
from keystoneclient import session as ksc_session
ksc_session.Session(...)

# or

from keystoneclient.session import Session
Session(...)
```